# Aws get S3 Bucket Size using java api

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have searched on google about efficient way to get metadata about S3 bucket like its size and number of files in it. I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/84815/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket) link discussing such problem. But it's for PHP and aws cli using cloud-watch. I want to know is there some java api to fetch the s3 bucket metadata?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the extensive documentation of the AWS S3 Java library here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/overview-summary.html

Answering your question, you can use getSize() for getting the size of an object in S3 and you can iterate over all of your files to get the size of your bucket.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html#getSize()

S3 does not support gathering disk usage directly (meaning not iterating through all of the items) but you can use CloudWatch to get the data you would like to use with a single request.

Example query:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/S3 --start-time 2016-01-01T10:00:00 --end-time 2016-02-12T01:00:00 --period 86400 --statistics Average --region us-east-1 --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=www.streambrightdata.com Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage
```

Returns:

```
{
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2016-02-05T10:00:00Z",
            "Average": 54027423.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2016-02-03T10:00:00Z",
            "Average": 52917504.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2016-02-04T10:00:00Z",
            "Average": 53417421.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2016-02-07T10:00:00Z",
            "Average": 54949563.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2016-02-01T10:00:00Z",
            "Average": 24951965.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2016-02-02T10:00:00Z",
            "Average": 28254636.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2016-02-06T10:00:00Z",
            "Average": 54577328.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        }
    ],
    "Label": "BucketSizeBytes"
}
```

AWS Java SDK for CloudWatch:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html

Comment: I have millions of files in buckets, iterating them takes too much time. I was hoping is there some fastest approach to achieve this?

Comment: hi Istvan! thanks for your response, But is there similar java api for cloudwatch?

Comment: Have a look at the period 86400 parameter. it splits up the response to chunks specified with that.

Answer (score 1):

with awssdk Java2.x

```
    Set<String> fileTypes = new HashSet<>();
    ListObjectsResponse listObjResp = amazonS3Client.listObjects(ListObjectsRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).build());
    int iCount=1;
    //********************************************************************//
    log.info("listObjResp.isTruncated() : "+listObjResp.isTruncated());
    String nextMarker = null;
    do {
        String sKey = null;
        List<S3Object> s3ObjList = listObjResp.contents();
        for (S3Object s3Obj: s3ObjList) {
            sKey = s3Obj.key();
            String[] sKeyValues = sKey.split("\\.");
            if(sKeyValues.length==2) {
                fileTypes.add(sKeyValues[1]);
            }else {
                fileTypes.add(NO_FILE_EXT);
            }
            ++iCount;
        }
        nextMarker = listObjResp.nextMarker();
        log.debug("listObjResp.nextMarker() : "+nextMarker);
        listObjResp = amazonS3Client.listObjects(ListObjectsRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).marker(nextMarker).build());
    } while (nextMarker !=null);
    
    log.info("iCount of '"+bucketName+"': "+(iCount-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MinioAdminClient` and its `getDataUsageInfo()` method to get all the info you need.

It can be connected via this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.minio/minio/8.5.3)
and configured in the same way as `MinioClient` by passing parameters with the help of a builder instead of a constructor.

```
@Bean
public MinioClient minioClient(
        @Value("${aws.endPoint}") String endPoint,
        @Value("${aws.accessKey}") String accessKey,
        @Value("${aws.secretKey}") String secretKey) throws InvalidPortException, InvalidEndpointException {

    return new MinioClient(endPoint, accessKey, secretKey);
}

@Bean
public MinioAdminClient minioAdminClient(
        @Value("${aws.endPoint}") String endPoint,
        @Value("${aws.accessKey}") String accessKey,
        @Value("${aws.secretKey}") String secretKey){

    return MinioAdminClient
            .builder()
            .endpoint(endPoint)
            .credentials(accessKey, secretKey)
            .build();
}
```

Link to the file in GitHub Repo: https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/adminapi/src/main/java/io/minio/admin/MinioAdminClient.java#L593

Answer (score 0):

You need the bucket name, but this solution relies on AWS CloudWatch since S3 does not directly support getting bucket size at the present time (Feb 2024).

With Amazon CloudWatch to get the stats of an s3 bucket (which includes size as a dimension) it would be something like this (needs some refactoring):

```
  package com.xyz.abc.config;

import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatch;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class AwsCloudWatchMetricClient {
    public static final AmazonCloudWatch cw = AmazonCloudWatchClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    public static final String namespace = "AWS/S3";
    public static final String metricName = "BucketSizeBytes";

    public static double getAwsCloudWatchS3Metric(String bucketName) throws ResourceNotFoundException
    {
        double bucketStorageUsedInBytes = -1;

        final GetMetricDataRequest getMetricDataRequest = new GetMetricDataRequest();
        final MetricDataQuery metricDataQuery = new MetricDataQuery();
        metricDataQuery.setId("s3StorageMetric");
        final MetricStat metricStat = new MetricStat();
        final Metric metric = new Metric();
        metric.setNamespace(namespace);

        final Dimension dimensionStorageType = new Dimension();
        dimensionStorageType.setName("StorageType");
        dimensionStorageType.setValue("StandardStorage");

        final Dimension dimensionBucketName = new Dimension();
        dimensionBucketName.setName("BucketName");
        dimensionBucketName.setValue(bucketName);

        List<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
        dimensions.add(dimensionBucketName);
        dimensions.add(dimensionStorageType);

        metric.setDimensions(dimensions);
        metric.setMetricName(metricName);
        metricStat.setMetric(metric);
        metricStat.setPeriod(86400);
        metricStat.setStat("Maximum");
        metricDataQuery.setMetricStat(metricStat);
        getMetricDataRequest.setMetricDataQueries(Collections.singletonList(metricDataQuery));
        final Date endTime = new Date();
        getMetricDataRequest.setEndTime(endTime);
        getMetricDataRequest.setStartTime(new Date(endTime.getTime() - (3600*100000)));


        GetMetricDataResult response = cw.getMetricData(getMetricDataRequest);

        boolean done = false;


        while(!done) {
//            ListMetricsResult response = cw.listMetrics(request);

            for(MetricDataResult metricGathered : response.getMetricDataResults() ) {
                System.out.printf(
                        "Retrieved metric data is %s", metricGathered.getValues());
                System.out.println(metricGathered.toString());
                System.out.println(metricGathered.getMessages());

                List<Double> vals = metricGathered.getValues();

                if(!vals.isEmpty()) {
                    bucketStorageUsedInBytes = vals.get(vals.size() - 1);
                    return bucketStorageUsedInBytes;
                }else {
                    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Problem adquiring S3 Maximum storage values for this bucket.");
                }

            }

            response.setNextToken(response.getNextToken());

            if(response.getNextToken() == null) {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        return bucketStorageUsedInBytes;
    }

}
```